# Xamarin: installed emulators don't show up on "Run" button of VS

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Android-App project. I already installed an emulator, it also shows up in the Android-Emulator-Manager. When I hit "Start" in the manager, everything works and the emulator and Android starts.

But in the tutorials etc. it always says, to see the application itself, there should be an element in the dropdown list at the Run/Debug Button with the emulators names on it after the first start through the manager.

In my case, there is no emulator listed. How can I "make it" show up there?

Comment: Your project is Android native project or Xamarin.forms project? If it is Xamarin.forms project, you need to **right-click** Android project, select **Set as Startup project**. If it is Android native project, and you have this problem, What is your Visual Studio version?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT It is Android native project, not Xamarin.forms and I use Visual Studio Community 2019 16.9.0. Thanks for helping...

Comment: Firstly, you can check you have installed the required software properly(having the Hyper-V option checked in Windows Features), then make sure that the **Minimum Android to target** is greater than or equal to at least one of your **Device Profiles** in **Visual Studio Emulator Manager**. You can Double-click Properties for Android project, go to Android Manifest Tab to check **Minimum Android version** and **target Android version**.

Comment: Hey @CherryBu-MSFT , I checked Hyper-V in Windows Features and applied it, and since my device profile is on Android Pie 9.0 I changed Minimum Android version AND target Android version to Android 9.0. Still my installed device is not showing up in the list and I cannot debug the program.

Comment: Does someone have an idea? Thanks for helping!